# PostgreSQL: Filter select query by comparing against other rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, filter

Suppose I have a table of Events that lists a `userId` and the `time` the Event occurred:

```
+----+--------+----------------------------+
| id | userId |            time            |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
|  1 |     46 | 2020-07-22 11:22:55.307+00 |
|  2 |    190 | 2020-07-13 20:57:07.138+00 |
|  3 |     17 | 2020-07-11 11:33:21.919+00 |
|  4 |     46 | 2020-07-22 10:17:11.104+00 |
|  5 |     97 | 2020-07-13 20:57:07.138+00 |
|  6 |     17 | 2020-07-04 11:33:21.919+00 |
|  6 |     17 | 2020-07-11 09:23:21.919+00 |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
```

I want to get the list of events that had a previous event on the same day, by the same user. The result for the above table would be:

```
+----+--------+----------------------------+
| id | userId |            time            |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
|  1 |     46 | 2020-07-22 11:22:55.307+00 |
|  3 |     17 | 2020-07-11 11:33:21.919+00 |
+----+--------+----------------------------+
```

How can I perform a select query that filters results by evaluating them against other rows in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using an EXISTS condition:

```
select t1.*
from the_table t1
where exists (select *  
              from the_table t2
              where t2.userid = t1.userid -- for the same user
                and t2.time::date = t1.time::date -- on the same
                and t2.time < t1.time); -- but previously on that day
```

Comment: Marking this as correct as it was the the most succinct and easy to understand / adapt. I cannot comment on performance at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(time) over (partition by userid, time::date order by time) as prev_time
      from t
     ) t
where prev_time is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cab50f5dcd7ffee046b6037cbf24519d) is a db<>fiddle.

Or `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid, time::date order by time) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAG()` to find the previous row for a user. Then a simple comparison will tell if it occured in the same day or not.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select
    *,
    lag(time) over(partition by userId order by time) as prev_time
  from t
) x
where date::date = prev_time::date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function :

```
SELECT id , userId , time
  FROM
  (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId, date_trunc('day',time) ORDER BY time DESC) AS rn,
          t.*
     FROM Events
   ) q
 WHERE rn > 1
```

in order to bring the latest event for UserId who takes place in more than one event.